# Superimposed glyphs and super/subscripts

Tags: symbols, stackengine

I am using `stackengine` to superimpose a `\cup` and `\^{}` to create a cup with a head of an arrow on the right endpoint. This works in normal size but if I use the new symbol as a super/subscript, then either the new symbol does not reduce its size or  the circumflex does not stay aligned (when adding `\text`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\cupr}{\topinset{\^{}}{$\cup$}{-0.7pt}{2.55pt}}
\newcommand{\cuprr}{\text{\topinset{\^{}}{$\cup$}{-0.7pt}{2.55pt}}}

\begin{document}

$$\cupr^{\cupr^{\cupr}} \qquad   \cup^{\cup^{\cup}} \qquad \cuprr^{\cuprr^{\cuprr}}  $$

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters here are good for Computer Modern fonts. For other fonts, adjust them (by eye).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cupr@tip}{\text{\raisebox{-0.1ex}{$\m@th\hat{}$}}}
\newcommand{\cupr}{\mathbin{\cup\cupr@}}

\newcommand{\cupr@}{%
  \mathchoice
  {\mkern-1.35mu\cupr@tip}
  {\mkern-1.35mu\cupr@tip}
  {\mkern-1.55mu\cupr@tip}
  {\mkern-1.875mu\cupr@tip}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\cup B$

$A\cupr B$

$A\cupr B_{A\cupr B_{A\cupr B}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. A follow-up question is this: with my previous definition I also had the cup with the arrow head to the left with `\newcommand{\cupl}{\reflectbox{\cupr}}` and the cap with the arrow head to the left with `\newcommand{\capl}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\cupr}}` . However this seems to fail with the new implementation. Is there a quick fix for these or I have to modify your code to accommodate each of these cases one by one?

Comment: @Minkowski They need a rather good massage, I'm afraid.